# Python: How can I update the list in a function?

Tags: python-2.7, list

In the following executable program I created a list. There is also a function to delete specific tuple. Whe I run this program the user is prompted to enter an elelment. After then you see I give the `remove_tuple_from_list()`-function the once created list and the element to be deleted. Now I have a problem: The print after the calling function shows me the same element in the list. I assumed as soon as I submitted the `list_tuple` to the `remove_tuple_from_list()`-function and the corresponding element was removed from the list, that the once created list was updated.

My idea is that I give an existing list to a function, edit it and then update the existing list.

```
list_tuple = [("100", 'AAA'), ("80", 'BBB'), ("20", 'CCC'), ("40", 'DDD')]

def remove_tuple_from_list(list_tuple,
                           delete_element,
                           index = 0):

    list_tuple = [element for element in list_tuple if not element[index] == delete_element]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print "Before: list_tuple", list_tuple
    print ""
    delete_element = raw_input('Enter Element to be deleted: ')

    remove_tuple_from_list(list_tuple = list_tuple, delete_element = delete_element)

    print "After: list_tuple", list_tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input()` returns a string, not a tuple. You should use `input()` instead so that your input can be evaluated as a tuple. Your `remove_tuple_from_list()` also does nothing to remove `delete_element` from `list_tuple` because it's comparing `element[index]` to `delete_element` when it should simply compare `element` to `delete_element`. But also, it's assigning a new list reference to `list_tuple` so the caller's `list_tuple` never gets updated. You should update `list_tuple` with a slice operator instead:

```
list_tuple = [("100", 'AAA'), ("80", 'BBB'), ("20", 'CCC'), ("40", 'DDD')]

def remove_tuple_from_list(list_tuple,
                           delete_element):
    list_tuple[:] = [element for element in list_tuple if not element == delete_element]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print "Before: list_tuple", list_tuple
    print ""
    delete_element = input('Enter Element to be deleted: ')

    remove_tuple_from_list(list_tuple = list_tuple, delete_element = delete_element)

    print "After: list_tuple", list_tuple
```

Given an input of `("100", 'AAA')`, the above outputs:

```
After: list_tuple [('80', 'BBB'), ('20', 'CCC'), ('40', 'DDD')]
```